# MKPinAnnotationView pinColor

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

I can't figure out why a MKPinAnnotationView associated (in theory) with a MKPointAnnotation doesn't appear on the map. In fact, the pin appears but it isn't purple as it should be...

Here is the code:

```
MKPointAnnotation *myPersonalAnnotation= [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
myPersonalAnnotation.title= [appDelegate.theDictionary objectForKey:@"theKey"];
myPersonalAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(6.14, 10.7);
MKPinAnnotationView *myPersonalView=[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myPersonalAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"hello"];
myPersonalView.pinColor=MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
[myMap addAnnotation:myPersonalAnnotation];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create an annotation view different from the default red pin, you have to create and return it in the map view's `viewForAnnotation` delegate method.

The map will automatically call the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method whenever it needs to show some annotation (either the built-in user location or annotations you add).

Remove the local creation of `myPersonalView` from before the call to `addAnnotation` and implement the `viewForAnnotation` method instead.

For example:

```
//in your current method...
MKPointAnnotation *myPersonalAnnotation= [[MKPointAnnotation alloc]init];
myPersonalAnnotation.title= [appDelegate.theDictionary objectForKey:@"theKey"];
myPersonalAnnotation.coordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(6.14, 10.7);
[myMap addAnnotation:myPersonalAnnotation];

//...

//add the viewForAnnotation delegate method...
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    //if annotation is the user location, return nil to get default blue-dot...
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;

    //create purple pin view for all other annotations...
    static NSString *reuseId = @"hello";

    MKPinAnnotationView *myPersonalView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:reuseId];
    if (myPersonalView == nil)
    {
        myPersonalView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:reuseId];
        myPersonalView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;
        myPersonalView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }
    else
    {
        //if re-using view from another annotation, point view to current annotation...
        myPersonalView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return myPersonalView;
}
```

Make sure the map view's `delegate` property is set otherwise the delegate method won't get called.
In code, use `myMap.delegate = self;` (eg. in `viewDidLoad`) or make the connection in Interface Builder if `myMap` is an `IBOutlet`.